# Can I make a git branch that uses .astro while the main branch does not?

Tags: html, git

I have a personal site that uses vanilla HTML and CSS. I am wanting to transition to .astro. I do not want to make a whole new repo, just to copy and paste files into the repo after it is done.

I would like to make a 'dev' branch and then when I'm done, merge to master. Is that possible? to have a dev branch that utilizes .astro while the main branch is vanilla?

Comment: What is ".astro"? But sure, why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

`Git` doesn't really care about your code/language/framework. It just cares about file names and their content.

It's perfectly okay to create a branch whose content is different from the `main` branch and then merge back.